# save image from local directory(not uploading) by Converting base64 data uri to file object using form data

Tags: reactjs, image, file, post, base64

I am trying to save image in database from a local directory(not uploading) by importing in reactjs.First I define the image by importing.Then i save the path in state But when i try to save the image it shows failed.This is the file format which i import from directory shows in the state:

```
 data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANS==........
```

i want to convert it to file object like this:

```
{name: "Copy of 8.jpg", 
    lastModified: 1586437734537,
    lastModifiedDate: Thu Apr 09 2020 19:08:54 GMT+0600 (Bangladesh Standard Time),
    webkitRelativePath: "", 
    size: 1172382, …}
```

This is what i have done so far for saving the local image:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import service from "../../../static/images/projectImage/service.png";//this is the image



    class ReactImage extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
    
            this.state = {
                apiUrl: config.publicRuntimeConfig.publicRuntimeConfigValue.apiUrl,
                parentList: [],
                file: service,//imported imagestored in state
    
            };
            
    
    
        }
   
        saveRequirementImage = () => {
            var data = new FormData();
            data.append("fileToUpload[]", this.state.file);
            axios.post(this.state.apiUrl + '/api/v1/visitImageRequirementInfo/save', data, config)
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log("response", response);
                    if (response.data.status === "success") {
                    }
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log(err);
                });
        };
    
    
        render() {
    
            return (
                <div className="app">
                    <input id="files" type="file"  type="file"/>
                    <button type="button">Submit</button>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }
    export default ReactImage;
```

How can i convert the base64 image format to file object?

Answer (score 0):

React cannot access your file system directly. Try this solution for downloading your image file.

```
handleChange(event) {
  this.setState({
    file:event.target.files[0]
  }, () => {
    this.downloadFile(this.state.file);
  });
}

downloadFile = (file) => {

  const blob = new Blob(
    [ file ],
    { type: 'image/jpeg' }
  );
  const href = await URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  const link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = href;
  link.download = 'your file name' + '.jpeg';
  document.body.appendChild(link);
  link.click();
  document.body.removeChild(link);
}
```

Comment: I dont want to download the image.I want to save it into the database.May be my title is misleading.what if i dont want to upload any image.On the file state if i just set the directory of the image.